# Show boot info on character LCD

Tags: gpio, lcd, gpiozero, adafruit

Is it possible to show boot log or info on a character LCD that the Raspberry Pi is still booting?

I'm using a generic 16x2 character LCD

Comment: Besides `cron` as per @aklingam's answer you can try to make a systemd script that runs at boot. (something like this https://askubuntu.com/questions/919054/how-do-i-run-a-single-command-at-startup-using-systemd). I'm not sure when it gets called if you enable the unit.

Comment: `systemd` could be much better as it runs earlier(?) than `cron` [(1)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188042/running-a-script-during-booting-startup-init-d-vs-cron-reboot). I'll try it out, thanks!

Comment: I just realized showing boot log on a 16x2 character LCD is a bit ambitious and absurd. I will go ahead with showing text info instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a simple python script that runs on startup with Cron. That script would display whatever you want for a small amount of time and then end. This would effectively tell you when your Pi's done with booting or if it still is.

You can enter this to edit crontab: `crontab -e`. Select Nano or any editor you're comfortable with and add a line like this: `@reboot python3 /home/pi/your_script.py`. I recommend you read the documentation for Cron if you haven't used it before: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/cron.md.

Edit: If you want it to be on during startup and off once booting is over, you could use a transistor to create an inverter (NOT Gate).

[image: schematic]

Comment: This is what I'm going for if I couldn't do it during boot. I'd like to display on the character LCD **during** boot.